# transformation matrix of reduced row echelon form

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I can compute the reduced row echelon form R of a matrix C in Matlab using the command `R = rref(C)`.

However, I would also like to keep track of the performed steps, that is, to obtain the transformation matrix T that gives me TC = R. This matrix should, to the best of my knowledge, be implicitly computed when using Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Is there a way to get T? Maybe a workaround? In the [matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rref.html), I couldn't find any information. Are there maybe rref-functions in other programming languages that would return T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fact that elementary row operations are equivalent to multiplying with an
elementary matrix on the left. Let `c` be a matrix of size (mxn);

```
z= rref([c eye(m)]); % [c I] is multiplied by some matrix T
% the result is [rref(c) T]
r= z(:,1:n); % the reduced row echelon form of c
t= z(:,n+1:end); % now we have T
```